# record is not updating

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have tried a lot to solve this small problem...I am trying to update a record in PHPmyadmin database.

```
$query = 'UPDATE movie SET 
                    movie_name = "'.$_POST['movie_name'].'";
                    movie_year = '.$_POST['movie_year'].';
                    movie_type =   "'.$_POST['movie_type'].'";
                    movie_leadactor =  "'.$_POST['movie_leadactor'].'";
                    movie_director =  "'.$_POST['movie_director'].'";
                    movie_running_time = "'.$_POST['movie_time'].'";
                    movie_cost = "'.$_POST['movie_cost'].'";
                    movie_takings = "'.$_POST['movie_earn'].'"';
```

but when I put this query in sql it shows an error.

this is my simple query.....

```
UPDATE movie SET movie_name = "XXX"; movie_year = 2010; movie_type = "7"; movie_leadactor = "4"; movie_director = "6"; movie_running_time = "90 "; movie_cost = "6.0 "; movie_takings = "22.0 "
```

[image]

How do I solve it? please help

error is on movie_year. error code is 1064

Comment: you should accept one of the answers if it helped you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you are using '**;**' instead of '**,**' seperator....modify like this with comma seperator '**,**'

```
$query = 'UPDATE movie SET 
                movie_name = "'.$_POST['movie_name'].'",
                movie_year = '.$_POST['movie_year'].',
                movie_type =   "'.$_POST['movie_type'].'",
                movie_leadactor =  "'.$_POST['movie_leadactor'].'",
                movie_director =  "'.$_POST['movie_director'].'",
                movie_running_time = "'.$_POST['movie_time'].'",
                movie_cost = "'.$_POST['movie_cost'].'",
                movie_takings = "'.$_POST['movie_earn'].'"';
```

And also try to escape the post values with '**mysql_real_escape_string**'

Comment: you need to remove ';' also

Answer (score 3):

use `,` instead of `;` at the end of each line

```
UPDATE movie 
SET movie_name = "XXX", 
movie_year = 2010,
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the comma part

```
$query = 'UPDATE movie SET 
                    movie_name = "'.$_POST['movie_name'].',";
                    movie_year = '.$_POST['movie_year'].',;
                    movie_type =   "'.$_POST['movie_type'].',";
                    movie_leadactor =  "'.$_POST['movie_leadactor'].',";
                    movie_director =  "'.$_POST['movie_director'].',";
                    movie_running_time = "'.$_POST['movie_time'].',";
                    movie_cost = "'.$_POST['movie_cost'].',";
                    movie_takings = "'.$_POST['movie_earn'].'"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$movie_name=$_POST['movie_name'];
$movie_year=$_POST['movie_year'];
$movie_type=$_POST['movie_type'];
$movie_leadactor=$_POST['movie_leadactor'];
$movie_director=$_POST['movie_director'];
$movie_time=$_POST['movie_time'];
$movie_cost=$_POST['movie_cost'];
$movie_earn=$_POST['movie_earn'];

$query = "UPDATE movie SET movie_name ='$movie_name', movie_year = '$movie_year', movie_type ='$movie_type', movie_leadactor ='$movie_leadactor', movie_director ='$movie_director', movie_running_time ='$movie_time', movie_cost ='$movie_cost', movie_takings ='$movie_earn'";
```

And add this to check any error :

```
if (!mysql_query($query))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

This should work perfectly.