# PHP: Record is not updating in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

My problem is in updating the SQL record. It fetches SQL data into form correctly (For editing) but when I press save edits button it returns following erro inside input field:
****Notice**:  Undefined variable: row in **C:\xampp\htdocs\edit.php** on line **46****
Please can you tell me how to fix it

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "zz224466";
$database = "zain";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $id = $_GET["edit"];  //Get id of sql table from other php page.
    echo $id; //It gives true result. It means that $_GET method above gets id of sql table correctly


    $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM product where product_id=$id");



    if ($res == FALSE) {
        die("Error");

    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);// Getting row from sql of specific id above selected above




    if (isset($_POST['Edit'])) {  ///Checking if Edit button has been pressed
        $product_category = $_POST['product_category'];
        $product_id = $id;

//// SQL query
        $sql_category = "UPDATE product SET product_category='$product_category' WHERE product_id=$id";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql_category)) {

        }

    }
}
    ?>

////////////////////HTML FORM/////////////////////////
<form method="post" action ="edit.php" id="contact-form">


    <input type="text" name="product_category" placeholder="product_category" value="<?php echo $row['product_category'];//It prints sql record in input field which is to be updated and it prints correctly. But when I press edit button it gives above mentioned error ?>"/>


    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Edit" value="Save Edits" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-right: 15px; border-radius: 4px;">

    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly tell me that how to fix it

Comment: This is because there is no value of $id once you hit the edit button.try to again send it on form submit .

Comment: Because `$_GET["edit"] != $_GET["Edit"]`

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: `<input type="text" name="product_id"  placeholder="product_id" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>"/>` I have wrote this inside form tag but still not working @Abilash Bansal

Comment: @Saty `$_GET["edit"] != $_GET["Edit"]` Where??

Comment: this line `if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {` you input name is `name="Edit"` so use ` `if(isset($_GET['Edit'])) {` instead

Comment: `$_GET['edit']` and `$_POST['Edit']` so, where is `$_GET['edit']` coming from?

Comment: Your post uses the POST method to send its data. You're using $_GET["edit"] to get the id for your data, which is not filled when submitting your form. Use a hidden input field with the name "product_id" and the right value to get it out of $_POST["product_id"] , then remove all the $_GET stuff.

Comment: This get method is not related to form element. @Saty

Comment: @Saty You're using it in the same function though, do you expect your code to remember what the 'id' is? That is not how it works, you need to do everything in the same run!

Comment: Get method is being used to get id from other page which is actually embedded into link tag.

Comment: It is not fetching id directly from SQL

Comment: I mentioned above it echoes id correctly.

Comment: Problem is with row variable

Comment: Not working:( Though I have tried it before posting this question @Nana

Comment: If I use `if(isset($_GET['edit']))` and `if (isset($_POST['Edit']))` conditions separately then `$id` and `$row` are not usable in `if (isset($_POST['Edit']))` condition as they are local variables of `if(isset($_GET['edit']))` condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [record is not updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103163/record-is-not-updating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Because, when you are pressing submit button. It's going to **edit.php** with `POST` value and no `GET` parameters (after pressing `Edit` submit button. So, browser is unable to find `$id` resulting to it, no `$row` values.)

```
<input type="text" name="product_category" placeholder="product_category" value="<?php if(isset($row['product_category'])) { echo $row['product_category'];}?>"/>
```

for example, `https:www.example.com/edit.php?edit=1`

after pressing `submit` button, `URL` changes to

```
https:www.example.com/edit.php
```

So, no `edit=1`

**Updated Code**

Change your `<form>` to

```
<form method="post" action ="edit.php?edit=<?echo $_GET['edit'];?>" id="contact-form">
```

Additional to what i did before.

**Full Updated Code** (See lines where i have written `Change Here`)

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "zz224466";
$database = "zain";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $id = $_GET["edit"];  
    echo $id; 
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM product where product_id=$id");
    if ($res == FALSE) {
        die("Error");

    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    if (isset($_POST['Edit'])) {  
        $product_category = $_POST['product_category'];
        $product_id = $_GET['edit']; // Change Here

        // Changes here 
        $sql_category = "UPDATE product SET product_category='$product_category' WHERE product_id=$product_id";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql_category)) {

        }
    }
}?>
    // Changes here in form tag 
    <form method="post" action ="edit.php?edit=<?echo $_GET['edit'];?>" id="contact-form"> 
          <input type="text" name="product_category" placeholder="product_category" value="<?php if(isset($row['product_category'])) { echo $row['product_category']; }?>"/>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Edit" value="Save Edits" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-right: 15px; border-radius: 4px;">
          </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It stops displaying error but record is not updating yet

Comment: See my answer @ZainFarooq

Comment: Hi @ZainFarooq: You didn't responded to my answer.

Comment: Hi,, Sorry for late responding. I just switch to programming today.

Comment: You are at very little mistake. You forgot to add hidden input field for product_id into form and that id would be used in update query for sql